# whats wrong in this update statement :?

Tags: sql-server-2005, sqldatasource

whats wrong in this update statement :

```
declare @s1from datetime
UPDATE Table1 SET Product = @Product , fare = @fare, s1from = convert(datetime,convert(datetime,@s1from,103),120)
```

Comment: I don't know.  What error do you get?

Comment: You do not need to create a new user for every question you ask. Forgive me if I am wrong but it looks like you are already registered as Akki, Sanju, Sanjeev, Sumit, Sumit (again), user594849 and possibly also Dhruv. Or perhaps these questions are homework and all students in your class is here asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

this expression: 
convert(datetime,convert(datetime,GETDATE(),103),120) works fine, so if you get an error you might forget about setting the value of @s1from, there is no line in your code. Try

`DECLARE @s1from datetime`

`SET @s1from = GETDATE()`

`SELECT convert(datetime,convert(datetime,@s1from,103),120)`